# Converting struct into a char

Tags: c, struct, char

I have a problem where I need to convert a the name of a struct variable into a `char`. For example:

```
struct CARINFO a;
```

When my function takes an argument of `CARINFO a`, I want to use both `a` and `"a"` in the function.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I *think* you are talking about the C language, can you confirm this?

Comment: A better answer could probably be provided if you said to what purpose you want to do this, but the short answer is no, you can't do this.

Comment: yes this is in c. 

this is what the car info struct looks like. 
{
 /* The location of the front of the car.  As all cars are assumed
    to be facing either north or west, this location represents
    the northwest segment of the car */
 LOCATION front;
 /* The orientation of the car */
 ORIENTATION orientation;
 /* The length of the car */
 int length;
} CARINFO;
unfortunately i can't change it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a macro to pass both the pointer to your struct and its name to the actual function.

```
struct bar {
    // blah
};

void actual_foo(struct bar *b, char *bname) {
    // whatever
}

#define foo(bar) actual_foo(&(bar), #bar)

int main() {
    struct bar b;
    foo(b);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do in C is to use a single macro to define both the string and the variable. There's no runtime inspection that would allow you to rediscover the name of a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by making the function into a macro, and using the # operator (stringification) to get the name of hte argument.

For example:

```
#define MYFUNC(x) \
do { real_func(x); printf("parameter name: " #x "\n"); } while (0)
```